# Use Column Value as Content in Another Element

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have `MyTable` structured as below:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
-----------------
ValueA  | ValueB
```

And would like to produce XML like below:

`<ValueA>ValueB</ValueA>`

This doesn't work but it's the closest I get.  I get a syntax error; apparently you can't use a column value in the `ROOT` function.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT ColumnB as "data()"
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT(ColumnA)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to create a string containing your xml concatenating the columns' values and then casting it to xml:

```
--create table variable to hold sample data 
declare @MyTable table( ColumnA nvarchar(50),ColumnB nvarchar(50) ) 

--populate sample data 
insert into @MyTable select 'ValueA', 'ValueB'

select * from @MyTable 

SELECT cast('<' + ColumnA + '>' + ColumnB + '</' + ColumnA + '>'  as xml)
FROM @MyTable
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: This is okay, but you must be aware, that this will break, if `ColumnB` includes forbidden characters. The linked answer shows a more secure solution.